# Merge values of dictionary into one if keys match condition

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary called, say, `tempDict` which is filled as such:

```
tempDict = {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 120, 'b_ext1': 4, 'd': 1021, 'a_ext1': 21, 'f_ext1': 12}
```

In my setup, I need to loop over the keys and if for any key that has a '_ext1' suffix, I want to rewrite or create a new dictionary keeping an unaltered key (preferably without the 'ext1') but with the values merged.

i.e.:

```
newDict = {'a': 121, 'b': 204, 'c': 120, 'd': 1021, 'f_ext1':12}
```

Notice, the last entry in the dictionary should be unchanged as there is no  `'f'` *unsuffixed* with `'_ext1'`

The values themselves won't be integers, however the operation is similar.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: how is a:121. didnt get

Comment: 'a' :100 and 'a_ext1': 21
I want to merge both to give 'a':121

Comment: by merging u mean addition(+) ?

Answer (score 1):

```
newDict = {}
for k in tempDict:
    if k.endswith("_ext1") and k[:-5] in tempDict:
       newDict[k[:-5]] = newDict.get(k[:-5],0)+tempDict[k]
    else:
       newDict[k] = newDict.get(k,0)+tempDict[k]
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the keys (items) in the sorted order and sum or add values. This works because keys like `"a"`, `"f"` sort before "`a_ext1"`, `"f_ext1"`:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for k, v in sorted(tempDict.items()):
...     if k[0] in d:
...         d[k[0]] += v
...     else:
...         d[k] = v
... 
>>> d
{'a': 121, 'c': 120, 'b': 204, 'd': 1021, 'f_ext1': 12}
```